# Text in helper won't translate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, slim-lang

So here's the problem:
Let's say, I have mails. The text inside is fully translated and everything is just fine. May it look like this (we're using SLIM on this project):

```
= t('foo.bar')
= t('foo.bar')
= t('foo.bar')
= thank_you_signature
```

So this `thank_you_signature` is a helper method from `ApplicationMailerHelper`. It is rather simple:

```
  def thank_you_signature
    SIGNATURE_TEMPLATE.render(self)
  end
```

```
 SIGNATURE_TEMPLATE = Slim::Template.from_heredoc <<-SLIM
    p.foo.bar #{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.foo')}
    foo.bar #{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.bar')}
  SLIM
```

So this is how it looks. And the problem is, it does not translate this `= thank_you_signature`. I have two locales, RU and EN. There are both, but in my mails, even though all the text is in english (as I choose my locale as user), this exact part remains in russian.

The first thing I checked was yml file, of course, but everything seems fine, there are no differences between `ru.yml` and `en.yml` files.

I've been on it for almost two days and I really don't get what's the trick here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
SIGNATURE_TEMPLATE = Slim::Template.from_heredoc <<-SLIM
  p.foo.bar #{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.foo')}
  foo.bar #{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.bar')}
SLIM
```

The `#{...}` string interpolation is done by Ruby when it is evaluating the heredoc so `Slim::Template` just sees a string like this:

```
p.foo.bar return-value-from-I18n.t...
foo.bar return-value-from-I18n.t...
```

and the `I18n.t` calls will use the default locale (probably US English).

You want Slim to handle the string interpolation so that the `I18n.t` calls are made when the template is rendered (i.e. when the locale is set to what you want it to be). To do that, you need to get the `#{...}` string interpolation past the heredoc by escaping it as `\#{...}`:

```
SIGNATURE_TEMPLATE = Slim::Template.from_heredoc <<-SLIM
  p.foo.bar \#{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.foo')}
  foo.bar \#{I18n.t('helpers.mailers.bar')}
SLIM
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this a while back was with a template file and loading that.

```
# app/templates/signature_template.slim
h1
  = I18n.t 'some_key'
```

```rb
# app/helpers/signature_helper.rb
def signature_template
  path = Rails.root.join('app/templates/signature_template.slim')
  
  Slim::Template.new(path).render(Object.new)
end
```